# access page's notes via app token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

according to fb's documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) i don't need a user_access_token to retrieve the notes of a public page, an app_access_token should be enough. however, when i sent request like https://graph.facebook.com/starbucks/notes?access_token=my_app_token, i got the reply that a user access token is required.

my questions are:

- did i misinterpret the documentation?
- anyone else has the same problem?
- anything i can do about it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there's something wrong in the `notes` connection. I honestly don't think that there's a wrong info in the documentation (but a bug in this specific connection).

I see a [reported bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/168306969940914) about this issue (reported by you?), but with a funny response from Facebook! Obviously the guy is just copy/pasting this "standard" *official* response and closing bugs randomly!

**EVERYONE READING THIS DO THE FOLLOWING:**

1. Create a **public** page (or use an existing one)
2. If the Notes app is not added to your page, Edit Page -> Apps -> Locate the Notes app and Edit Settings -> Add tab
3. Now add a test note
4. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
5. Choose one of your apps and GET the page's notes to see the current note: `/page_id/notes`
6. Go the to the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/), copy that app `access_token` and replace the one in the explorer with it
7. Result:

   ```
   {
     "error": {
       "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
       "type": "OAuthException"
     }
   }
   ```

If this was reproducible, then subscribe to the [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/168306969940914) and confirm by clicking on "Yes" for the reproducible question.

Comment: yes, i reported the issue about a week ago and not very happy with the response. i see lots of fb page building/customization companies busy monetize this part of fb but seems i was the only one got the issue, that really bothers me. thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are welcome, hopefully someone will reopen the bug and you'll get a REAL response this time!

Answer (score 0):

> Access to certain Pages may be restricted based on demographic information such as the current user's age or location. Access may
>   also be restricted to only a Page's administrators.

Based upon your findings above, as well as this quote from the documentation link you shared above, this tells me that maybe Starbucks is only allowing their page admins access to the notes connection of their page.

Try creating a page yourself, play around with the various settings and see what is available with and without tokens.  Shouldn't take you too much time.

Comment: thanks for the reply. however, i don't think it's the case b/c there is no problem to retrieve posts via https://graph.facebook.com/starbucks/posts?access_token=my_app_token. both posts and notes share the same demographic info settings of the page.

Comment: Do you get any notes from starbucks if you use a user access token?

Comment: yes, i do. in fact it's not only happens to starbucks, but all the public pages i've tested.